# If tree sap looked like blood, would we be less inclined to cutting trees down?

Tags: society, psychology, forestry

**Compassion**

We often feel more concern about the pain inflicted to animal that have expression that are more intuitive to us. We are more compassionate with a chimpanzee than a trout, in part because we are sharing similar expression mechanism (esp. facial expression).

**Deforestation**

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation)

> trees are cut down to be used for building or sold as fuel, (sometimes in the form of charcoal or timber), while cleared land is used as pasture for livestock and plantation

According to [forest facts](http://www.rain-tree.com/facts.htm)

> Rainforests once covered 14% of the earth's land surface; now they cover a mere 6%
>
> 78 million acres [of forest] lost every year!

**My world**

Imagine a world where [tree sap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sap) is abundant and blood looking; dark red and similar viscosity as blood. A bit like what we can see on these images

[image] [image]

Imagine the origin of the color is unrelated to anything that is of economic or ecological interests.

**Question**

Would we be less inclined to cutting trees down?

Comment: Hello, I can see that you're fairly new to the site. Unfortunately, your question does not appear to be quite within scope for WB SE. Not only are you asking multiple questions, but you're also asking ***opinion-based*** ones at that. I would answer that no, it wouldn't in any way stop us from "doing our thing", just as it doesn't stop us from farming cattle, etc. And those animals actually bleed. You should try reframining your question.

Comment: We hunt and eat animals and treat them inhumanely, they sure contain a lot of blood.

Comment: @AndreiROM I reduced my post to a single question. I doubt I solved the opinion-based part that you describe though but I might have to read the exact definition of what we call opinion-based on WB.SE to really undersatnd why my question is off-topic here.

Comment: In my experience, most trees leak very little sap when you cut them.

Comment: @Remi.b The text associated with voting to close a question as primarily opinion based is "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." Humans are such a diverse and varied group that it's basically impossible to say with any certainly how they will respond to something in anything but the most general of terms. If we look at the answers you already have most of them are just opinions with little to no facts to back them up.

Comment: I don't believe there can be sure, objective answer to this question.

Comment: Bark could be a "normal" color, but the flesh of the tree would be also red.

Comment: "“If trees could scream, would we be so cavalier about cutting them down? We might, if they screamed all the time, for no good reason.”  - Jack Handey.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

People would generally get over it, like we are already getting over slaughtering animals. Of course there would be some cults which oppose cutting the trees, maybe they will be Ok with using driftwood, but generally that should make no difference.

Comment: would probably give psychopaths a more gratuitous outlets to vent their desires on

Answer (score 5):

Since man has killed his fellow man despite the color of blood, and since we slaughter millions of cows, pigs, and chickens a year despite the color of animal's blood, sap being bloodlike would not prevent humanity from cutting down trees.

Answer (score 5):

## Probably Not

While compassion for animals, especially ones we keep as pets, is high, it doesn't translate into other animals. We keep and slaughter livestock, they bleed. We hunt wildlife, they bleed.

### Economic Pressure

Human history says that if it pays, we'll harvest it. And we'll do it in the most efficient way possible, even if it's arguably inhuman or self-destructive. Modern livestock is kept crammed in inhuman conditions, yet we happily buy the resulting cheap meat at the store with little thought. Similarly, trees will be felled for the lumber, bleeding or not.

### Psychological Distance

A boneless chicken breast has as much to do with slaughtering a chicken as a smooth wooden plank has to do with cutting down a tree.

In modern society, only the people keeping the livestock or working in the slaughterhouse have to see their conditions or blood or even what is recognizably an animal. Similarly, only the wood workers really ever see a whole tree. The average consumer is removed and only sees a sanitized version. Our current view of meat says we can live with that.

### Ethical Wood?

What you might have is people claiming that wood is unethical, or that it must be harvested ethically, similar to leather. Perhaps there will be people who do not want to use wooden utensils or building materials. Whether this will have an impact on larger society is another question. Will it have as large an impact as vegetarianism? Or the smaller impact of veganism?